# vcvarsall.bat missing after installing Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild, x86-64, visual-studio-2019

Previously on my Visual Studio 2017, I had the file vcvarsall.bat located at this location - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
But later my office installed Visual Studio 2019 and I dont see vcvarsall.bat file anywhere.
Can anyone advise how to get the file, I did read some forums but could not find any solution. 
Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can find the `vcvarsall.bat` file for VS2019 at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Your VS Edition\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat`

And one point we should know, this file is under `VC` folder. So it's part of C++ workload. If you can't find the file in the location above, please make sure you've installed the C++ related workload. (In VS, go Tools menu=>Get Tools and Features=>Install the `Desktop Development With C++` workload)

In addition: The path you mentioned above refers to the `vcvarsall.bat` for VS2015. The [`vcvarsall.bat` for VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43570522/10910450) should be under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\...` directory. VS2015=>vs version 14.0 while VS2017=>15.0.

Comment: Hi - for some reason my folder goes : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS  , as in there is no other option than Community etc in the following folders. I tried a search of vcvarsall in the whole folder and nothing turned up, do you know if I can download the file seperatley?

Comment: what is the location in case of only the build tools without full vs2019 installed? I am trying to build with VC140 using VS2019 build tools.